# shell: reuse backgrounded emacsclient windows, when invoking emacsclient

Tags: bash, emacs

Is it possible to reuse backgrounded emacsclient windows, when invoking emacsclient?

Here's some background information (I mainly use emacs in terminal mode, not gui frames)

When the computer boots, an emacs daemon is started.
In the OS X terminal when I want to open a file, I do `emacsclient /filename -nw`

Now when I want to do bash stuff I press C-z to background emacs.
Now emacs appears in the `jobs` command. The `fg` command would also
make it re-appear.

But while I'm browsing around in bash, I see another file I want to open.
Now, how can I reuse that minimized emacsclient session with a single command?

Comment: I'm not sure you can. The suspended process is stopped. I believe it needs to be started again before you can interact with it. If you could detach it without suspending it that would work I think.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, put this in your `.bashrc`:

```
ec() {
    kill %emacsclient 2> /dev/null
    emacsclient -nw --eval '(find-file "'"$PWD/$1"'")'
}
```

Open files with `ec file.txt`. It's a bit hacky, but I think it will do what you want it to.

I open the file `find-file` so it'll stay open after you close the Emacs window (`C-x C-c`). Then when you open a new file, I kill the old Emacs window and open a new one. The effect is that the old file stays open forever, so it seems like you reused the Emacs window.